# how to make checkbox checked work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In my project, `$('#cenDiv').html(data)` can work successfully in `ajax`. Then I want to click the checkbox of `selAllAttId`, and do something;

If I use `onclick="selAllAtt()"`, and `selAllAtt()` method can be called successfully, but `$(this).attr("checked")` became to be true always after finishing the `selAllAtt()` method, so `$(this).attr("checked")` is always false and `alert("checked")` always can not work.

So I want to change another way with `$('#selAllAttId').on("change",function(){})` But unlucky, `alert("test)` can no work. Who can help me?

Here is js code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
 $('#selAllAttId').on("change",function(){
  alert("test");//can not work
  });
});


function corpAnn()
{   
 $.ajax({
        dataType:'html',
        type:"POST",
        url:"oat.php",
        data: {oaAnn:oaAnn},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#cenDiv').html(data);
        }
      });     
}

 function selAllAtt(){
  alert("checkbox");
  var xzyId=document.getElementById('xzyId');//fetch other table id
  var checked=xzyId.getElementsByTagName('input');//fetch all table checkbox successfully
  if($(this).attr("checked"))//always false.          
  {
    alert("checked");
    for(i=0;i<checked.length;i++)
    {
      checked[i].checked=true;
    }
  }
  else
  {
   alert("delete");
   for(i=0;i<checked.length;i++)
   {
    checked[i].checked=false;
   } 
  }
});
</script>

<div id="cenDiv"></div>
```

The code of oat.php is:

```
 echo '<td  style="color:Maroon" bgcolor="#888888">
       <input type="checkbox" id="selAllAttId" onclick="selAllAtt()">
       <b>Num</b>
       </td>';
```

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is. A function called by `onclick` does not have any special `this` context related to the element. Stop using `onclick` and use modern unobtrusive event listeners

Comment: @charlietfl, I have tested for $(this).checked, but fail again

Comment: `this` has nothing to do with the element the onclick occurs on. Suggest you study some tutorials on javascript user events

Comment: @charlietfl, can you show me the code for $('#selAllAttId').on("change",function(){})

Comment: using that approach then `this` **is** the element ... use `prop()` instead of `attr()` to return a boolean http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the native HTML node like this:

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('selAllAttId');
if(checkbox.checked)          
{
  // do something
}else{
 // do something else
}
```